# Passing MudBlazor snackbar options Action<SnackbarOptions> as function parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I defined a Action delegate called *snackbarOptions* so I can use it when adding snackbar instead of declaring it in *Snackbar.Add()* function call

```
Action<SnackbarOptions> snackbarOptions = (options) =>
{
            options.RequireInteraction = true;
            options.Action = "UKLONI DUPLIKAT";
            options.ActionColor = Color.Error;
            options.ActionVariant = Variant.Filled;
            options.Onclick = async snackbar =>
            {
                await DeleteDependency(readStep, readDependency);
            };
 };
```

And now whenever I want to add snackbar I just pass the *options* parameter. The add function is itself a parameter to a function.

```
duplicatesValidation.CheckForDuplicates((x, y, z) => Snackbar.Add("Message", MudBlazor.Severity.Warning, snackbarOptions));
```

This works fine, however, when I try to pass *snackbarOptions* as a function parameter so I can call *Snackbar.Add* in *CheckForDuplicates()* function I get an object reference error

```
duplicatesValidation.CheckForDuplicates(snackbarOptions);
```

EDIT:
So to summarize:
**This works:**

```cs
public void CheckForDuplicates(Action<string, Severity, Action<SnackbarOptions>> SnackBarAdd) 
{
...
}
```

calling -

```cs
duplicatesValidation.CheckForDuplicates((x, y, z) => Snackbar.Add("Message", MudBlazor.Severity.Warning, snackbarOptions))
```

**This doesn't:**

```cs
public bool CheckForDuplicates(Action<SnackbarOptions> options)
{
...
}
```

calling -

```cs
duplicatesValidation.CheckForDuplicates(snackbarOptions)
```

EDIT 2:
*Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ... EditDependenciesDialog.razor.cs:line 188* code at that line: `duplicatesValidation.CheckForDuplicates(duplicatesSnackbarOptions)` *DuplicatesValidation.cs:line 35* code at that line: `Snackbar.Add("x", Severity.Warning, options);`

Comment: Could you update the original post with that exception? Also make sure that you're using `snackbarOptions` the delegate not `options` the delegate parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-functions-vs-lambda-expressions) instead to avoid missing object references.

When you create and store a delegate at runtime there may be a chance that the delegate you create isn't assigned when you call it.

When using a local method instead it's pre-compiled and can be referenced at any time and anywhere within it's scope.

```cs
void snackbarOptions(Options options)
{
        options.RequireInteraction = true;
        options.Action = "UKLONI DUPLIKAT";
        options.ActionColor = Color.Error;
        options.ActionVariant = Variant.Filled;
        options.Onclick = async snackbar =>
        {
            await DeleteDependency(readStep, readDependency);
        };
 }
```